# Display only 10 records after that an button too show all

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, limit

I was wondering how to get a limit on the displayed records and for example a limit of 10 and after that their needs to be a button to get all the topics their are. I was wondering how to display it that way

Functions code:

```
public function get_topics(){
        $getTopic = $this->database->query("
        SELECT topics.*, klanten.foto, klanten.voornaam, boards.topic, ledenpagina.ledenpagina_id, klanten.achternaam FROM topics 
        LEFT JOIN ledenpagina ON ledenpagina.ledenpagina_id = topics.ledenpagina_id
        LEFT JOIN klanten ON topics.klant_id=klanten.id
        LEFT JOIN boards ON topics.board_id=boards.id
        WHERE ledenpagina.ledenpagina_id=:ledenpagina_id 
        ORDER BY id ASC");
        $this->database->bind(":ledenpagina_id", $_SESSION['ledenpagina_id']);    
        $topics = $this->database->resultset();

        return $topics;   
    }
```

The php code:

```
<section class="col-md-8 connectedSortable">
   <div class="clearfix paddingbottom10"></div>
    <div class="box box-info">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading main-color-bg">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Topics</h3>
      </div>
      div class="panel-body">
       <?php                      
       $toppic = $app->get_topics();
       foreach($toppic as $topic){

         echo '<a href="https://####/reactie"> <div id="topic">';
         echo '<div id="topicimg">';
         if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'])) { 
          echo '<img class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'].'/'.$topic['foto'].'" />';
         } else {
            echo '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-user img-circle"></i>';
         }
         echo '</div><div id="topictekst">';
         echo '<b>'.$topic['topicnaam'].'</b>'; 
         echo ' - ' . $topic['voornaam'] . " " . $topic['achternaam'] ;
         echo '<span style="float:right; margin-top:15px; margin-left:5px;">'.implode($app->count_reactie($topic['id'])) .' reacties</span> <span style="float:right; color:lightgrey; margin-top:15px"class="fa fa-comment"></span>';
         echo '<hr><span class="badge bg-red">' . implode($app->boards($topic['board_id'])) . '</span>';
         echo ' laatste reactie: ' .$app->tijd_reactie($topic['id']) . ' door ' .$app->reactieDoor($topic['id']);
         echo '</div></div></a>';
        }
      ?>

   </div>
   </div>
/div><!-- /.box --> 
</section><!-- right col -->
```

This is my first question so please don't be to hard on me

Comment: Try using for instead of foreach with limit of 10 cycles. Than echo your button.

Comment: hey what your trying to achieve is called pagination check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2466051/6391281

Comment: @Eakethet I am kinda getting what u mean but not totally because what do I give that button? so it will display more? May I ask you to include a answer?

Comment: Why don't you add that limit to your database query?

Comment: @halfofmylive Well it depends. You can render rest of your results into some collapsed div. You can set limit 10 for query and the button will take you to next page (read about pagination as mentioned above). The button can send ajax request for next 10 posts etc. What is the behaviour that suits you?

Comment: @NicoHaase because I want it too display more when I press a button

Comment: Then you should write some logic to modify that database query...

Comment: What do you mean? @NicoHaase

Comment: Can you help me in my case?@NicoHaase

Answer (score 0):

[Paging by SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2012-sql-order-by-offset-fetch-next-rows.aspx) can be implemented with the new features on ORDER BY clause like Offset and Fetch Next

Here is a sample query

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY ID OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

If you parameterize the Offset count like (page number * page row count) you can build a paging structure for your web page